# Simplifying a big O expression O(k + (n-k)Logk + kLogk) = O(n + klogk)?

Tags: big-o

On an exercise to find the k smallest or largest elements in an array A, there's a solution that produces a O(k + (n-k)Logk + kLogk) runtime. However, my friend told me this expression equals O(n + klogk). I'm not sure if he's right or not, can anybody help me with the math on this?

Comment: Be careful with "equals" and the equal sign on Big O expressions. They are not used in the mathematical sense and in particular `a = b` does not imply `b = a` there! In your case, `O(k) = O(n)` because `k <= n`, just as example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything is exactly as you describe it, then your friend was careless with his arithmetic. Quite obviously k + (n-k)Logk + kLogk = k + nLogk, and not n + kLogk. If n is larger than k then the first one can be arbitrarily large compared to the second one.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `k log k + n log k`? I don't see how it can become linear in `k` when `k log k` is part of the original sum.